# Time-dependent Hamiltonian and the Liouville-von Neumann equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, density-operator

If I have a quantum system described by a time-independent Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, then the Liouville-von Neumann equation is

\begin{align}
i\hbar\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial t}=[\hat{H},\hat{\rho}]\,,
\end{align}

where $\hat{\rho}$ is the density matrix. What happens if the Hamiltonian is explicitly time-dependent, such that $\hat{H}=\hat{H}(t)$? Is the Liouville-von Neumann equation the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Hamiltonian is time-dependent the evolution of a pure state is 
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = {\mathcal T} exp\left[ -\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^t d\tau H(\tau)\right] |\psi(0)\rangle = U(t; t_0) |\psi(0)\rangle
$$
where $\mathcal T$ is the time-ordering operator and 
$$
i\hbar\dot{U} = H(t) U(t, t_0)
$$
Then a density matrix evolves according to
$$
\rho(t) = U(t; t_0) \rho(0) U^\dagger (t; t_0) 
$$
and you can check that taking the time derivative gives
$$
i\hbar\dot{\rho} = \left[ H(t), \rho(t)\right]
$$

Comment: I have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]=\frac{1}{i\hbar}H(t)\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]$, but how do I treat the time-ordering operator? Is it true that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\mathcal{T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]\right)=\mathcal{T}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]\right)$?

Comment: If this is so, then why would $\mathcal{T}\left(H(t)\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]\right)=\left(H(t)\mathcal{T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tH(\tau)d\tau\right]\right)$?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You may want to take a look at Sec.5.2.1 in https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch5.pdf. The time ordered exponential ${\mathcal T}\exp\left[-(i/\hbar)\int_{t_0}^t{d\tau\; H(\tau)}\right]$ is a compact way of writing a series where each term is a nested integral of the form $$\int_{t_0}^t{d\tau_1\int_{t_0}^{t_1}{d\tau_2\; \dots \int_{t_0}^{t_{n-1}}{d\tau_n H(\tau_1) H(\tau_2)\dots H(\tau_n)}}}$$.